# Node.js on Ubuntu: Chilld process with piped stdio, does not emit stdout and stderr

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, stdio

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.2 (run in a virtual machine on mac).

I've installed Node.js v16 (via official software channel) and observed an extremely weird issue. Child processes spawned with `studio: 'pipe'` do not emit any `stdout` or `stderr` data.

Steps to reproduce:

*child.js*

```js
console.log("Some text");

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Other text")
}, 100)

setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 1000);
```

*main.js*

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');

const child = childProcess.spawn('node', ['child.js'], { stdio: 'pipe'});

if (child.stdout) {
    console.log("Attach std listeners")
    child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log("Child stdout:", String(data)));
    child.stderr.on('data', data => console.log("Child stderr:", String(data)));
}

child.on('close', (...args) => { console.log("Child closed", args); });
```

Running `node test.js` produces following in Ubuntu terminal for me:

```
Attach std listeners
CLOSED [ 0, null ]
```

*(when I run it on macOS, I get as expected multiple `Child stdout: Other text` in output)*

While if I change `stdio` to `inherit` in main script, the output from child process is exposed:

```
Some text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Other text
Child closed [ 0, null ]
```

It signals to me that the child process is run without issues but for some reason, no `stdout` and `stderr` are emitted by a child when its output is supposed to be piped.

The same issue occurs with other Node.js versions I've checked (v14, v17, v18nightly)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is when Node.js is installed via Snap dependency manager (so official Ubuntu Software installer).

Software is then sandboxed in read-only containers, with restricted access to other system parts, and as it shows that cannot work for Node.js

Solution: Do not install Node.js via Snap, install via apt instead